# SQL UNION over all possible values for a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now, what I am doing is

```
select t1.Team, t2.Total - SUM(t1.Diff) OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Amount
from @trend t1 
INNER JOIN @totalRecordsToday t2 on t1.Team = t2.Team
WHERE t1.Team = 'Team1'
GROUP BY t1.Team, t1.Date, t1.Diff, t2.Total, t1.NewlyAdded, t1.Resolved, t1.Diff
UNION
select t1.Team, t2.Total - SUM(t1.Diff) OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Amount
from @trend t1 
INNER JOIN @totalRecordsToday t2 on t1.Team = t2.Team
WHERE t1.Team = 'Team2'
GROUP BY t1.Team, t1.Date, t1.Diff, t2.Total, t1.NewlyAdded, t1.Resolved, t1.Diff
```

And so on, for each distinct t1.Team value. This is a hard-coded approach as I am doing a union for each value of t1.Team that I know. Is there a way for me to programmatically do a union over all distinct t1.Team values?

Comment: You're already grouping by t1.Team, so your 'Team1' is going to be separated from your 'Team2'.  Just remove your WHERE and the UNIONs.  Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `partition by` clause:

```
select t1.Team,
       t2.Total - SUM(t1.Diff) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Team
                                     ORDER BY t1.DATE DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Amount
from @trend t1 INNER JOIN
     @totalRecordsToday t2
     on t1.Team = t2.Team;
```

I find it odd that you would know about cumulative sums but not `partition by`.  In any case, all window functions support `partition by`.  Some also support `order by`.